# React form control issue but displays fine locally

Tags: reactjs

I get this odd react error during compilation, but it works fine locally.

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./src/components/dashboard/addTicket.js
SyntaxError: /home/ubuntu/test

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<Select
                                    labelId="demo-simple-select-placeholder-label-label"
                                    id="demo-simple-select-placeholder-label"
                                    label=""
                                    value={ticket.year}
                                    inputProps={{
                                        name: 'year',
                                        id: 'age-native-simple',
                                    }}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    displayEmpty
                                    className={classes.selectEmpty}>
                                    <MenuItem value={'SP13'}>SP13</MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem value={'SU13'}>SU13</MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem value={'FA13'}>FA13</MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem value=
                                </Select>
                            </FormControl>
```

/src/components/dashboard/addTicket.js: Unexpected token (265:1)

263 |                                     className={classes.selectEmpty}
264 |                                 >

> 265 | <<<<<<< HEAD
> |  ^
> 266 | =======
> 267 |                                     <MenuItem value={'SP13'}>SP13
> 268 |                                     <MenuItem value={'SU13'}>SU13

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! task-managment@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the task-managment@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2021-06-21T17_05_48_876Z-debug.log

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the snippet you shared. Do you have a git conflict in the file? <<<<< HEAD? It would be great if you can share the line 263 to line 268 of code

Comment: Well it does say git conflict, but not sure why the snippet appears